Time out while .\gradlew clean React-native existing Project in New windows setup
I had an existing Project that was built on old system with react-native.

Did new Setup for react-native in new System with same config JDK11, Android Studio and node@latest
Cloned repo
Tried ./gradle clean inside Android folder.

\android> .\gradlew clean
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip failed: timeout**
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:122)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:80)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:82)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:551)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2944)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2853)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1949)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1611)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:100)
        ... 7 more


android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

